# Views Inside Row Of RecyclerView Not Accessible, Always Return Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I assigned views inside ViewHolder but when try to access **Button** in *OnBindViewHolder* or try to add *OnClickListerner* in *OnCreateViewHolder*, App going to crash and says "Attempt to invoke virtual method on null object reference"... But on other hand when try to setText on TextView it work

**Adapter Class**

```
public class DownloadManagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DownloadManagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static String TAG = "rrDebug";

    private void AskForDelete(final ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApplication.getInstance().getContext())
                //set message, title, and icon
                .setTitle("Delete video")
                .setMessage("Are you sure want to proceed ?")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete)

                .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        new File(DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().get(viewHolder.position).getPath()).delete();
                        viewHolder.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.INVALID_STATUS, 0, 0);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    private FileDownloadListener downloadItemListener = new FileDownloadSampleListener() {

        private ViewHolder checkCurrentHolder(final BaseDownloadTask task) {
            final ViewHolder tag = (ViewHolder) task.getTag();
            if (tag.id != task.getId()) {
                return null;
            }

            return tag;
        }

        @Override
        protected void pending(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
            super.pending(task, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.updateDownloading(FileDownloadStatus.pending, soFarBytes
                    , totalBytes);
            tag.downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_pending);
        }

        @Override
        protected void started(BaseDownloadTask task) {
            super.started(task);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_started);
        }

        @Override
        protected void connected(BaseDownloadTask task, String etag, boolean isContinue, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
            super.connected(task, etag, isContinue, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.updateDownloading(FileDownloadStatus.connected, soFarBytes
                    , totalBytes);
            tag.downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_connected);
        }

        @Override
        protected void progress(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
            super.progress(task, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.updateDownloading(FileDownloadStatus.progress, soFarBytes
                    , totalBytes);
        }

        @Override
        protected void error(BaseDownloadTask task, Throwable e) {
            super.error(task, e);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.error, task.getLargeFileSoFarBytes()
                    , task.getLargeFileTotalBytes());
            DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().removeTaskForViewHolder(task.getId());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paused(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
            super.paused(task, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.paused, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
            tag.downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_paused);
            DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().removeTaskForViewHolder(task.getId());
        }

        @Override
        protected void completed(BaseDownloadTask task) {
            super.completed(task);
            final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
            if (tag == null) {
                return;
            }

            tag.updateDownloaded();
            DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().removeTaskForViewHolder(task.getId());
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener fancyButtonClickListeners = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getTag() == null) {
                return;
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.dlmng_item_download:
                    // to start
                    final DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManagerModel model = DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().get(holder.position);
                    final BaseDownloadTask task = FileDownloader.getImpl().create(model.getUrl())
                            .setPath(model.getPath())
                            .setCallbackProgressTimes(100)
                            .setListener(downloadItemListener);

                    DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl()
                            .addTaskForViewHolder(task);

                    DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl()
                            .updateViewHolder(holder.id, holder);

                    task.start();
                    break;
                case R.id.dlmng_item_pause:
                    // to pause
                    FileDownloader.getImpl().pause(holder.id);
                    break;
                case R.id.dlmng_item_view:
                    Log.i(TAG, "No Player To Play File");
                    break;
                case R.id.dlmng_item_delete:
                    // to delete
                    AskForDelete(holder);
                    //new File(DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().get(holder.position).getPath()).delete();
                    //holder.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.INVALID_STATUS, 0, 0);
                    break;
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cell_download_manager, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        // set onClickListener on FancyButtons
        Log.d(TAG, "setOnClickListener on FancyButtons");
        viewHolder.downloadItemDownloadBtn.setOnClickListener(fancyButtonClickListeners);
        viewHolder.downloadItemPauseBtn.setOnClickListener(fancyButtonClickListeners);
        viewHolder.downloadItemPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(fancyButtonClickListeners);
        viewHolder.downloadItemDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(fancyButtonClickListeners);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManagerModel model = DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().get(position);

        viewHolder.update(model.getId(), position);
        viewHolder.downloadItemName.setText(model.getName());

        DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl()
                .updateViewHolder(viewHolder.id, viewHolder);


        if (DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().isReady()) {
            final int status = DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getStatus(model.getId(), model.getPath());
            if (status == FileDownloadStatus.pending || status == FileDownloadStatus.started ||
                    status == FileDownloadStatus.connected) {
                // start task, but file not created yet
                viewHolder.updateDownloading(status, DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getSoFar(model.getId())
                        , DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getTotal(model.getId()));
            } else if (!new File(model.getPath()).exists() &&
                    !new File(FileDownloadUtils.getTempPath(model.getPath())).exists()) {
                // not exist file
                viewHolder.updateNotDownloaded(status, 0, 0);
            } else if (DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().isDownloaded(status)) {
                // already downloaded and exist
                viewHolder.updateDownloaded();
            } else if (status == FileDownloadStatus.progress) {
                // downloading
                viewHolder.updateDownloading(status, DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getSoFar(model.getId())
                        , DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getTotal(model.getId()));
            } else {
                // not start
                viewHolder.updateNotDownloaded(status, DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getSoFar(model.getId())
                        , DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getTotal(model.getId()));
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder.downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_loading);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return DownloadManagerActivity.DownloadManager.getImpl().getTaskCounts();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView downloadItemName;
        private TextView downloadItemStatus;
        private TextView downloadItemSize;
        private TextView downloadItemSpeed;
        private ProgressBar downloadItemProgressBar;
        private ImageButton downloadItemPlayBtn;
        private ImageButton downloadItemDownloadBtn;
        private ImageButton downloadItemPauseBtn;
        private ImageButton downloadItemDeleteBtn;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            downloadItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_Name);
            downloadItemStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_status);
            downloadItemSize = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_size);
            downloadItemSpeed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_speed);
            downloadItemProgressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_progress_bar);
            downloadItemPlayBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_item_view);
            downloadItemPlayBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_item_download);
            downloadItemPauseBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_item_pause);
            downloadItemDeleteBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dlmng_item_delete);
        }

        /**
         * viewHolder position
         */
        private int position;
        /**
         * download id
         */
        private int id;

        public void update(final int id, final int position) {
            this.id = id;
            this.position = position;
        }

        public void updateDownloaded() {
            downloadItemProgressBar.setMax(1);
            downloadItemProgressBar.setProgress(1);

            downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_completed);
            // Play Button Visible
            Log.d(TAG, "play button visible as item downloaded");
            downloadItemDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            downloadItemPauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            downloadItemPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void updateNotDownloaded(final int status, final long sofar, final long total) {
            if (sofar > 0 && total > 0) {
                final float percent = sofar
                        / (float) total;
                downloadItemProgressBar.setMax(100);
                downloadItemProgressBar.setProgress((int) (percent * 100));
            } else {
                downloadItemProgressBar.setMax(1);
                downloadItemProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            }

            switch (status) {
                case FileDownloadStatus.error:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_error);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.paused:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_paused);
                    break;
                default:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_not_downloaded);
                    break;
            }

            // Play Button Visible
            Log.d(TAG, "download button visible as item not downloaded");
            downloadItemDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);;
            downloadItemPauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            downloadItemPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        public void updateDownloading(final int status, final long sofar, final long total) {
            final float percent = sofar
                    / (float) total;
            downloadItemProgressBar.setMax(100);
            downloadItemProgressBar.setProgress((int) (percent * 100));

            switch (status) {
                case FileDownloadStatus.pending:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_pending);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.started:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_started);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.connected:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_connected);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.progress:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_progress);
                    break;
                default:
                    downloadItemStatus.setText(MyApplication.getInstance().getContext().getString(
                            R.string.dlmng_status_downloading, status));
                    break;
            }

            // Pause Button Visible
            Log.d(TAG, "pause button visible as item is currently downloading");
            downloadItemDownloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            downloadItemPauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            downloadItemPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    } }
```

**cell_download_manager.xml**

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     ...
>     android:background="@drawable/cell_download_manager"
>     ... >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         ... >
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/dlmng_download_Name"
>             ... />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/dlmng_download_status"
>             ... />
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             ... >
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/dlmng_download_size"
>                 ... />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/dlmng_download_speed"
>                 ... />
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>         <ProgressBar
>             android:id="@+id/dlmng_progress_bar"
>             ... />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/dlmng_item_download"
>         ... />
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/dlmng_item_pause"
>         ... />
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/dlmng_item_view"
>        ... />
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/dlmng_item_delete"
>         ... />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**Update section #1 Catlog in pastebin**
https://pastebin.com/D4wLVAMT

**Update Section #2 --> DownloadManagerActivity.class**
https://pastebin.com/i3bZDcB3

---

> Sorry For PASTEBIN but question length is limited

---

Comment: Can you also post the error message?

Comment: @grrigore yes of course, check the update section #1

Comment: I think you have to add your `setOnClickListener` to your `ViewHolder` class, into its constructor.

Comment: already did but same result, and one more thing this happened for Button Only not for other Views

Comment: By Button you mean the ImageButtons, right?

Comment: Button, ImageButtons and FancyButton (Library from Gitihub)......... That's why this problem is too strange

Comment: As I can see the error might be on line `209` or `27`, but I assume you have some imports in your `DownloadManagerAdapter` class and that might have shifted the code (I can't find the lines that might cause the error). Could you please update and include the whole file or just comment above the lines that might contain errors?

Comment: @grrigore yes of course, there is file DownloadManagerActivity which is importing allover in Adapter check the update section #2

Comment: All I'm saying is that you should somehow point to the lines that might cause the errors. I copy-pasted the code and my 209 line might not correspond to yours.

Comment: @grrigore please check the Update Section #2 now.... Its avail on PasteBin.... May be you help me more

Comment: You don't have to post the `DownloadManagerActivity` code, but the whole `DownloadManagerAdapter` code. Is that the whole code?

Comment: yes its the whole code, there is nothing more in DownloadManagerAdapter.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution with below codes..... assigned the clickListeners seperately and then use them in onBindViewHolder

**Here's what I did**

```
private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            assignViews();
        }

        private View findViewById(final int id) {
            return itemView.findViewById(id);
        }

        /**
         * viewHolder position
         */
        private int position;
        /**
         * download id
         */
        private int id;

        public void update(final int id, final int position) {
            this.id = id;
            this.position = position;
        }


        public void updateDownloaded() {
            dlItmProgressBar.setMax(1);
            dlItmProgressBar.setProgress(1);

            // Status: Download Complete
            dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_completed);
            downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void updateNotDownloaded(final int status, final long sofar, final long total) {
            if (sofar > 0 && total > 0) {
                final float percent = sofar
                        / (float) total;
                dlItmProgressBar.setMax(100);
                dlItmProgressBar.setProgress((int) (percent * 100));
            } else {
                dlItmProgressBar.setMax(1);
                dlItmProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            }

            switch (status) {
                case FileDownloadStatus.error:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_error);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.paused:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_paused);
                    break;
                default:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_not_downloaded);
                    break;
            }
            // Status Not Downloaded
            downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        public void updateDownloading(final int status, final long sofar, final long total, final String speed) {
            final float percent = sofar
                    / (float) total;
            dlItmProgressBar.setMax(100);
            dlItmProgressBar.setProgress((int) (percent * 100));

            switch (status) {
                case FileDownloadStatus.pending:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_pending);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.started:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_started);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.connected:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_connected);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.progress:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(String.format(MyApplication.getInstance().getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.dlmng_status_downloading),(int) (percent*100))); // + "at " + String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(speed)/1024)+"MB/s");
                    break;
                default:
                    dlItmStatus.setText(MyApplication.getInstance().getContext().getString(
                            R.string.dlmng_status_downloading, status));
                    break;
            }

            // Status Downloading
            downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        private TextView dlItmName;
        private TextView dlItmStatus, dlItmSize, dlItmSpeed;
        private ProgressBar dlItmProgressBar;
        private FancyButton downloadBtn, deleteBtn, pauseBtn, viewBtn;

        private void assignViews() {
            dlItmName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_Name);
            dlItmStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_status);
            dlItmSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_size);
            dlItmSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_speed);
            dlItmProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_progress_bar);
            downloadBtn = (FancyButton) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_download_btn);
            deleteBtn = (FancyButton) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_delete_btn);
            pauseBtn = (FancyButton) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_pause_btn);
            viewBtn = (FancyButton) findViewById(R.id.dlmng_view_btn);
        }

    }

    private static class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

        private FileDownloadListener taskDownloadListener = new FileDownloadSampleListener() {

            private ViewHolder checkCurrentHolder(final BaseDownloadTask task) {
                final ViewHolder tag = (ViewHolder) task.getTag();
                if (tag.id != task.getId()) {
                    return null;
                }

                return tag;
            }

            @Override
            protected void pending(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                super.pending(task, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.updateDownloading(FileDownloadStatus.pending, soFarBytes
                        , totalBytes, String.valueOf(task.getSpeed()));
                tag.dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_pending);
            }

            @Override
            protected void started(BaseDownloadTask task) {
                super.started(task);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_started);
            }

            @Override
            protected void connected(BaseDownloadTask task, String etag, boolean isContinue, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                super.connected(task, etag, isContinue, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.updateDownloading(FileDownloadStatus.connected, soFarBytes
                        , totalBytes, String.valueOf(task.getSpeed()));
                tag.dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_connected);
            }

            @Override
            protected void progress(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                super.progress(task, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.updateDownloading(FileDownloadStatus.progress, soFarBytes
                        , totalBytes, String.valueOf(task.getSpeed()));
            }

            @Override
            protected void error(BaseDownloadTask task, Throwable e) {
                super.error(task, e);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.error, task.getLargeFileSoFarBytes()
                        , task.getLargeFileTotalBytes());
                DownloadManager.getImpl().removeTaskForViewHolder(task.getId());
            }

            @Override
            protected void paused(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
                super.paused(task, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.paused, soFarBytes, totalBytes);
                tag.dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_paused);
                DownloadManager.getImpl().removeTaskForViewHolder(task.getId());
            }

            @Override
            protected void completed(BaseDownloadTask task) {
                super.completed(task);
                final ViewHolder tag = checkCurrentHolder(task);
                if (tag == null) {
                    return;
                }

                tag.updateDownloaded();
                DownloadManager.getImpl().removeTaskForViewHolder(task.getId());
            }
        };

        private View.OnClickListener playButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getTag() == null) {
                    return;
                }
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                // to start
                final DownloadManagerModel model = DownloadManager.getImpl().get(holder.position);
                final BaseDownloadTask task = FileDownloader.getImpl().create(model.getUrl())
                        .setPath(model.getPath())
                        .setCallbackProgressTimes(100)
                        .setListener(taskDownloadListener);

                DownloadManager.getImpl()
                        .addTaskForViewHolder(task);

                DownloadManager.getImpl()
                        .updateViewHolder(holder.id, holder);

                task.start();
            }
        };
        private View.OnClickListener pauseButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getTag() == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "pauseButtonClickListener: tag not present");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "pauseButtonClickListener: tag present");
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                // to pause
                FileDownloader.getImpl().pause(holder.id);
            }
        };
        private View.OnClickListener viewButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getTag() == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "viewButtonClickListener: tag not present");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "viewButtonClickListener: tag present");
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                // to play video
                Log.i(TAG, "viewButtonClickListener: no player for playing video");
            }
        };
        private View.OnClickListener deleteButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getTag() == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "deleteButtonClickListener: tag not present");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "deleteButtonClickListener: tag present");
                final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                // to delete
                if (doubleBackToDelete) {
                    new File(DownloadManager.getImpl().get(holder.position).getPath()).delete();
                    //holder.downloadBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.updateNotDownloaded(FileDownloadStatus.INVALID_STATUS, 0, 0);
                }
                doubleBackToDelete = true;
                Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getInstance().getContext(), "Please click again to DELETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doubleBackToDelete=false;
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(
                    LayoutInflater.from(
                            parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.cell_download_manager, parent, false));

            holder.downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(playButtonClickListener);
            holder.pauseBtn.setOnClickListener(pauseButtonClickListener);
            holder.viewBtn.setOnClickListener(viewButtonClickListener);
            holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(deleteButtonClickListener);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final DownloadManagerModel model = DownloadManager.getImpl().get(position);

            holder.update(model.getId(), position);
            holder.downloadBtn.setTag(holder);
            holder.deleteBtn.setTag(holder);
            holder.pauseBtn.setTag(holder);
            holder.viewBtn.setTag(holder);
            holder.dlItmName.setText(model.getName());

            DownloadManager.getImpl()
                    .updateViewHolder(holder.id, holder);

            //holder.downloadBtn.setEnabled(true);


            if (DownloadManager.getImpl().isReady()) {
                final int status = DownloadManager.getImpl().getStatus(model.getId(), model.getPath());
                if (status == FileDownloadStatus.pending || status == FileDownloadStatus.started ||
                        status == FileDownloadStatus.connected) {
                    // start task, but file not created yet
                    holder.updateDownloading(status, DownloadManager.getImpl().getSoFar(model.getId())
                            , DownloadManager.getImpl().getTotal(model.getId()), "");
                } else if (!new File(model.getPath()).exists() &&
                        !new File(FileDownloadUtils.getTempPath(model.getPath())).exists()) {
                    // not exist file
                    holder.updateNotDownloaded(status, 0, 0);
                } else if (DownloadManager.getImpl().isDownloaded(status)) {
                    // already downloaded and exist
                    holder.updateDownloaded();
                } else if (status == FileDownloadStatus.progress) {
                    // downloading
                    holder.updateDownloading(status, DownloadManager.getImpl().getSoFar(model.getId())
                            , DownloadManager.getImpl().getTotal(model.getId()), "");
                } else {
                    // not start
                    holder.updateNotDownloaded(status, DownloadManager.getImpl().getSoFar(model.getId())
                            , DownloadManager.getImpl().getTotal(model.getId()));
                }
            } else {
                holder.dlItmStatus.setText(R.string.dlmng_status_loading);
                //holder.downloadBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return DownloadManager.getImpl().getTaskCounts();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is straight forward

You are setting the fancyButtonClickListeners inside onCreateViewHolder

1. You don't have the clicked item reference in onClickMethod
2. You don't have data corresponding to the item clicked

Please move the clickListener operation into onBindViewHolder. this will fix the issue. Better use new OnClickListener() {} instead of fancyButtonClickListeners variable

Comment: Thanks for your try, I already tried this but not working....... this s something out of regular knowledge......